# How to extract a value which does not have any attribute in ruby watir

Tags: html, ruby, regex, text, watir

I have a response page where some text is present. There are no attribute based on which I can get the required text from response. Can some one please write me a code to do the same. I have attached the source here.

```
Mux isconnected
requesting...
response got
field id="0" value="0110"field id="3" value="000000"<BR>field id="4" value="000000010000"<BR>field id="6" value="000000010000"<BR>
Response - Success
<-- 0110 000326 33444489
```

In the above source I want to extract [ id="0" value="0110" ]
and then use value=0100 in next test steps.

I have the code to split the text and use only value as shown below

```
text = 'response got field id="0" value="525XXXXXXXXX66"' 
matcher = text.match(/value="(.+)"/) 
puts matcher.captures.first
```

But first I need to extract the require tag or text and assign that as 'text' in the above function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the first `field id="0" value="0110"` you can use this regex

```
/(field\s+id=".+?"\s+value=".+?")/.match(yourString)[1]
```

and use the first group. Groups in regexes allow you to get a particular part of text in your expression, eg using the regex `/ma(.+?)l/` against `manual` you'll get 'nua' in the first group, that is `/ma(.+?)l/.match('manual')[1]` will be e qual to 'nua'.

If you want to get the id of a specific value (eg 29) and id is always **before** value do this

```
str=29
myResult = /field\s+id="#{str}"\s+value="(.+?)"/.match(yourString)[1]
```

`value` is in `\1` group (that is `[1]`), thus `myResult` contains the number you need. Of course you can put anything in str.

Also look [here](http://rubular.com/r/nRvFb7JHRa), this is a working example of the regex you need!

**EDIT:**

I think I have correctly answered your question. Your further requests for clarifications make me think that you miss the programming background to accomplish this task. If you need to know anything else please post another question or spend some efforts in learning the programming language you are using. This community (as I understand it) doesn't welcome this kind of behaviour.

Comment: It is not the First filed which i want to extract. I actually have to extract Field 29 which I have not mentioned here as it would be too long. But what I need is like for specified ID like 2 or 3, I need to extract and save the corresponding value. I should be some how able to tell ruby to extract value of this ID and save it to some variable so that I can use it in later steps

Comment: When i implement this i get an error. I am very new to ruby and do not much understand the implementation. Here is the error I get.

auth.rb:126: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting keyword_end
newtext=field\s+id="38"\s+value="(.+?)"

Comment: Also in the proposed solution, I am not able to make out what is the group you have mentioned about and what is the value is in\1 which you are refering to. Request you to guide me thought the same

Comment: Thank you for the details. I am getting close to the solution now. I have implemented you solution this way. newvalue=/field\s+id="38"\s+value="(.+?)"/.match(yourtext)[1] but then I started getting this error - undefined local variable or method `yourString' for main:Object, so i did this text1='yourtext'


newvalue=/field\s+id="38"\s+value="(.+?)"/.match(yourtext)[1] and now I get this error 'undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)'. Can you please take a look and advice....

Comment: I tested the solution and work correct. But this is not completly solving the issue. See the text which you are referring is not some static text. It is what gets displayed on browser as a response to the request. And this text though remains in same pattern, the values changes for each response. It is like, the number of tags which gets displayed will always remain same and same does the field ID's only the corresponding values keep changing. So I need to capture Value of a filed ID for a perticular response... Can you please adivce if a above sloution can be modified accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure if you noticed my earlier comments. the variable 'yourtext' changes with every response. I am not sure how to get the resonse and pass it to variable 'yourtext'. Please advice.

Comment: I *think* I have correctly answered your question. Your further request for clarifications make me think that you miss the programming background to accomplish this task. If you need to know anything else please post another question or spend some efforts in learning the programming language you are using. This communiti doesn't welcome this kind of behaviour.

Comment: In Watir, you can get the text of the browser by doing `yourtext = @browser.text` where `@browser` is your Watir::IE object. If that is not what you are looking for, I agree you should start another question and provide more details regarding the tools you are using and what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i was looking for. I did not know how to get the yourtext value. Now it all work fine.... Thanks again......